# Capture inactive window via Java applet

Tags: java, linux, macos, applet, screenshot

is there a way for a trusted java applet running on a web page to capture another inactive (or even obstructed / minimized) window? I need this proccess to take place on the background, so screenshot of the whole screen is NOT a way to go.

I should be able to find a solution for Win32 using JNI + Win32 API, but I have no experience with OSX and Linux graphic environments. Would anyone point me the right direction, please?

Thank you!

Comment: for Win32, I'd suggest you check JNA instead of JNI for these kind of things.  Can't help regarding signed applets that said (may applets die a horrible death ;)

Comment: @Deor: (you tagged your question 'OS X').  On OS X you can forget about it, OS X doesn't work the same way  Windows does: a process doesn't have access to another process's "graphic memory".  Heck, on OS X there aren't even any documented allowing to find windows **names**... So capturing another process's windows *content* on OS X, I'd honestly forget about it.

Comment: @Webinator: Thank you for the OS X bit, I really know close to nothing about the system. What about a way to invoke a system command and grab its output? For example, if I were about to invoke screencapture command, would I be able to retrieve the output (it's just an example)? I believe trusted applet should grant me some interesting privileges that might be useful in this case, isn't that true?

Comment: well, from regular Java programs you can certainly call OS X programs as you want (like, say, by running some AppleScript/OsaScript).  You can take a screencapture directly from a Java program too, but you wrote *"screenshot of the whole screen is NOT the way to go"*.  From applets I've got no idea.